# let A be a square matrix show that

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$ be a square matrix

show that

a.

$(I-A)^{-1} = I+A+A^{2}+A^{3}$  if $A^{4} = 0$

b.

$(I-A)^{-1}= I+A+A^{2}+...+A^{n}$ if $A^{n+1} = 0$

I  tried to solve part a but I don't make sure if my way is correct or no

$(I-A)^{-1}\cdot (I+A+ A^{2} +A^{3}) ^{-1}  = I\to1$

$( I+A+A^{2}+A^{3})^{-1}\cdot(I-A)^{-1} = I\to2$

from $1$ and $2$ part $a$ is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Consider $(I-A)(I+A+A^2+A^3+...+A^n)\ =\ [I+A+A^2+A^3+...+A^n-(A+A^2+A^3+...+A^{n+1})]$.

Use $A^{n+1}=0$.